# I cannot import a large HTML body

Tags: 8, nodes, importing-exporting

Am using [content import](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport) module in drupal 8 to import nodes. For test i have defined like below

[image]

It works fine when smaller body content. But when the body is too large. Then the import is undone with no fail message.

**Test Case:**

I have unchecked the below in the configuration,

[image]

I turned on the **source** mode in ck editor and pasted large body html content. And saved the changes it works.

**Content Type:** Basic Page

**Sample Body Content(Formatted):**
[image]

Total lines will be around 500.

Is it possible to import the file attachment too?

Comment: How large is "too large"?

Comment: @PatrickKenny, It's around 500 lines(formatted). Updated screenshot in post.

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome by using the [Migrate CSV plugin](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/migrate-source-csv/using-the-migrate-source-csv-plugin), now i can able to import large body content.